# Can I render and display Markdown from Github into MEAN stack website dynamically?

Tags: github, markdown, web-deployment, mean-stack

I'm developing a website using the MEAN stack framework and wanted to know if there is any way I can dynamically render a Markdown page that lives on a Github repository.

I don't want to redeploy the site every time a change is made to the Markdown file.

Comment: Have you considered GitHub's [webhooks](https://help.github.com/articles/about-webhooks/)?

Comment: It looks like webhooks are for 'pushing' updates to a service. My question is more for how I can 'retrieve' the GitHub file and load it dynamically on the site when the site's page is requested and loaded? I quickly looked at GitHub API but they have rate limits that concern me.

Comment: No, webhooks notify you that an update is available for you to retrieve. If you push a change to GitHub, the webhook notifies a URL you set up that an update was made. You need to configure that URL (on your server) to call a script which retrieves the changes and processes them. So your question really is about how to respond to the webhook notice. Therefore, webhooks are not really the answer (thus my mentioning them in a comment). However if you don't want to use webhooks, that may change the answer slightly. But then how will your script know when there are changes to retrieve?

Answer (score 0):

Use [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com): push to the `gh-pages` branch and GitHub will do the markdown to HTML conversion and serve you the HTML (not rate-limited) at `http://yourusername.github.io/yourrepo`. Just make an HTTP call to that address to fetch your content.

If you want to do the Markdown to HTML conversion yourself, fetch the Markdown via [RawGit](https://rawgit.com/).